# ejecutar programa con php abriendo una terminal

Tags: php, cmd

lo que pasa es que actualmente estoy realizando un programa de PHP en donde ejecuto programas de C le doy entradas a partir de un archivo de texto

y guardo sus salidas para analizarlas, lo que pasa es que yo quiero que la salida salga con todo el formato, incluyendo saltos de linea por ejemplo al ejecutar este programa de C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int num1,num2,res;
printf("dame un numero ");
scanf("%d",&num1);
printf("dame otro numero ");
scanf("%d",&num2);
res=num1+num2;
printf(" el resultado de la suma es:%d",res);
return 0;
}
```

en el archivo de texto tengo las entradas que serian:

```
10
20
```

incluyendo el salto de linea, y lo ejecuto con php con el comando shell exec:

```
shell exec(programa<entrada.txt)
```

pero esto no me funciona pues me da la siguiente salida:

```
dame un numero dame otro numero el resultado de la suma es:30
```

y yo lo que necesito es que salga asi:

```
dame un numero
dame otro numero
el resultado de la suma es:30
```

espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias... dejo mi codigo en php que es muy sencillo

nota:como pueden ver antes de todo lo compilo

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/misestilos.css">
  <script src="jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="frmEntrada" method="post" action="ejecutar.php">
   Codigo:<input type="text" name="txtEntrada">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnEntrar" value="Enviar"> 
  </form>


  <?php 
   if (isset($_POST["btnEntrar"])) {
    $texto=$_POST["txtEntrada"];
    $salida="gcc $texto.c -o $texto";
    $respuesta=array();
    $estado;
    $res=exec($salida,$respuesta,$estado);
    
    if ($estado==1) {
     echo "El programa no fue encontrado o error de compilacion";
    }
    else{
     //tomar contenido de salida
     $manejador2=fopen("S".$texto.".txt", 'r');
     //bloquear archivo
     flock($manejador2, 2);
     //pasar contenido de archivo a arreglo
     $contenido2=fread($manejador2, filesize("S".$texto.".txt"));
     fclose($manejador2);


     $salida=shell_exec($texto."< E".$texto.".txt");
     
     var_dump($salida);
     echo "<div class='row'>";
      echo "<div id='cajas' class='col-sm-6'>";
      echo "<H1>Salida del Programa</h1><br>";
      echo "<p>$salida</p>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "<div id='cajas' class='col-sm-6'>";
      echo "<H1>Salida esperada</h1><br>";
      echo "<p>$contenido2</p>";
      echo "</div>";
     echo "</div>"; 
     echo "<input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' value='No pasa'' onclick='' />";
     echo "<input type='button' class='btn btn-success' value='Pasa'' onclick='' />";
    }

   }

   ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un problema de sintaxis en C. El problema es que no has añadido ningún salto de línea. Debes añadir la secuencia de escape `"\n"` para que aparezca un salto de linea, como por ejemplo:

```
printf("dame un numero \n");
```

Comment: Había pensando en eso pero es que la respuesta es un string entonces al momento de mostrarlo lo imprime en una línea aunque tenga saltos

Comment: Quieres decir que te imrpime `\n` ?

Comment: Osea sale igual la cadena al mostrarla pero al verla con el comando ver dump sale el string con saltos de linea

Comment: Creo que ya te entiendo. Si lo que quieres es que PHP imprima un salto de página entonces tienes que añadir `<br>` porque PHP no es capaz de interpretar `\n`. Prueba `printf("dame un numero <br>");`.

Comment: @PepoGonzalez, el que no se visualicen los `\n` no es culpa de `PHP`, sino de `HTML`, es decir, el motor de rendering del navegador. @Yept intenta imprimir el resultado usando [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php), ejemplo: `echo "<p>".nl2br ($salida)."</p>"`

Comment: @Marcos Toda la razón. Es HTML el que interpreta lo que imprime PHP. Por otra parte, también es verdad que nl2br es una solucion bastante más limpia, pero para que funcione no debe olvidar utilizar `\n` en su `printf()` tal y como dije al principio.